# Trying to change 'margin-top' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is what I'm trying to do :

```
$(function(){           
  $('div.item').css('margin-top',-(closest('img').height())/2+'px'); 
});
```

I want my `'<div class="item"'>`
to get `style="margin-top:XXXXXX; top:50%"`
where `'XXXXXX'` is equal to `(('div.item a img').height())/2`

======================================================

**EDIT : ( solved )
Final code for those who are interested :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
theWindow.resize(function() {
$('div.item').each(function(i){          
  $(this).css('top',(($(window).height())/2)-(($(this).first('img').height())/2)+'px'); 
});
}).trigger("resize");
});    
</script>
```

( i used only top attribute instead of top + margin-top )
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you need, especially if you have more than one `div.item`

```
$('div.item').each(function(){
    var r = $(this).find('img').first().height();
    $(this).css('margin-top', r/2 + 'px'); 
});
```

**EDIT**

You need to `.find()` the `img` and then select the `.first()` one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/JNMhC/3/

Comment: I tried this :
    `$('div.item').each(function(){
        var r = $(this).closest('img').height();
        $(this).css('margin-top', -r/2 + 'px'); 
    });`
But this is not working, on FF and Chrome.

Comment: Does it need to be `closest('img')`?  And do you want negative margins?

Comment: Yep, i wan't a negative margin. I use with position:absolute; and top:50%; to get the div center aligned.
Else, i tried this, which is working on FF, but not on chrome. And chrome doesn't return me any error in the console.
`$('div.item').each(function(){
    var r = $(this).find('img').height();
    $(this).css('margin-top', -r/2 + 'px'); 
});`

Comment: Remember you need the `.first()`

Comment: I tried your edit. The result is the same than the last one :-( It works on FF, but not on chrome. I think this is syntax is good, but the problem might come from somewhere else ... But i really don't know where :(

Comment: Problem solved. The negative was the problem, i stopped using it. I replaced my top:50% by a top:-50%
Thanks

Comment: Great. Glad to help. BTW: I removed the negative from my example.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are trying to do something like this :

```
$(function(){           
  $('div.item').css('margin-top',-($('div.item').closest('img').height())/2+'px'); 
});
```

But the image selector depends on your html configuration.
If you post some html markup, maby I could provide a better solution.

Comment: huh oO
This is working on FF, but not on chrome.
Maybe because i already have a listener on div.item ?

Comment: Thx for your help guys :-)

I found the bug :
Math.round(r/2 + 'px') is working.

I deleted the negactive and replaced for a top:-50% instead of top:50%

It seems that Chrome dos not accept negative values